# Two different local repos commit to one Github repo

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to have two repos with two different sets of folders and files both committing to one repo on Github? If so how do I set this up?

As in the following:

Repo 1

```
-Folder_1
-Folder_2
-Folder_3
```

Repo 2

```
-A_Folder
-B_Folder
-C_Folder
```

Github Repo

```
-A_Folder
-B_Folder
-C_Folder
-Folder_1
-Folder_2
-Folder_3
```

Comment: Why can't you use two github repos though?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about whether you want the content between them to be synced?

Comment: This is where a merge conflict would occur, I believe. I've never had a large project on git, so I've never dealt with this, but you'll have to handle which files and changes should be shared by the entire repo.

Say you committed and pushed one set of changes, but then you wanted to put the other one into it; the latter will overwrite the previous, and that may not be the outcome you want. Thankfully, it is git, so you should be able to simply reverse what you've done by using the checkout command. You should determine what works with what in each change, then decide what to do from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

You can do it in several ways:

1. Sub-tree / Branches
2. Submodules / Multiple repositories

Each one has its cons and pros of course.

---

#### 1. Sub-tree / Branches

Using this method you should have your code spread between different branches either explicitly or using sub-tree and you can merge the separate branches to a single repository.

[image]

---

#### 2. Submodules / Multiple repositories

Not exactly what you asked for since Submodules is splitting your repository into smaller ones and combine them together using SubModules

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can think of every local repository as remote and you can merge them into one new repository.

First, create a new repo with `git init` and make a commit (to have a master branch)

Then add the 2 repositories with `git remote add alias link`
Then fetch with `git fetch alias_names_of_2_repository`
(You can see branches with `git remote -a`)

Then for every remote repository, you need to create a local branch using;
`git branch newBranchName oldBranchNameInRemote`

Then use this to put these into a folder,

```
git checkout newBranchOfRepo1
mkdir directoryForOldRepo1/
git ls-tree -z --name-only HEAD | xargs -0 -I {} git mv {} directoryForRepository1/
git commit -m "random commit/"
```

Then merge with the main repository,
`git checkout master && git merge --allow-unrelated-histories newBranchOfRepo1`

Do these for every repository.